# Chilkat IMAP - how to check "Sent" mailbox name

Tags: autoit, chilkat-email

How to check how "Sent" mailbox is named ?
Somtimes I have to use "INBOX.Sent" sometimes "Sent",
I do can not relay on guess I must have a way to check what current name is.

Do you have a way to check it with Chilkat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get answer/solution to my problem:
I use This example [(PowerShell) Find the "Sent" IMAP Mailbox](https://www.example-code.com/powershell/imap_find_sent_mailbox.asp)

Here is my version:

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\PS1\ChilkatDotNet48_x64.dll"
$glob = New-Object Chilkat.Global
$success = $glob.UnlockBundle("Anything for 30-day trial")
if ($success -ne $true) {
    $($glob.LastErrorText)
    exit
}

$status = $glob.UnlockStatus
if ($status -eq 2) {
    $("Unlocked using purchased unlock code.")
}
else {
    $("Unlocked in trial mode.")
}
$($glob.LastErrorText)


$imap = New-Object Chilkat.Imap

$imap.Ssl = $true
$imap.Port = 993
# connect to server
$success = $imap.Connect("******")
if ($success -ne $true) {
    $($imap.LastErrorText)
    exit
}

# Login or authenticate in some way..
$success = $imap.Login("******","******")
if ($success -ne $true) {
    $($imap.LastErrorText)
    exit
}

# Get the list of mailboxes.
$refName = ""
$wildcardedMailbox = "*"

$mboxes = $imap.ListMailboxes($refName,$wildcardedMailbox)
if ($imap.LastMethodSuccess -eq $false) {
    $($imap.LastErrorText)
    exit
}

# The mailbox with the "/Sent" flag is the "Sent" mailbox.
# Likewise for Junk and Trash..
$i = 0
$("")
$("")
while ($i -lt $mboxes.Count) {
    if ($mboxes.GetName($i) -eq "Sent") {
        $("Sent mailbox (1): " + $mboxes.GetName($i))
        $(" >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,0)=" + $mboxes.GetNthFlag($i, 0))
        $(" >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,1)=" + $mboxes.GetNthFlag($i, 1))
        $("")
    }
    
    if ($mboxes.HasFlag($i,"\Sent") -eq $true) {
        $("Sent mailbox (2): " + $mboxes.GetName($i))
        $(" >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,0)=" + $mboxes.GetNthFlag($i, 0))
        $(" >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,1)=" + $mboxes.GetNthFlag($i, 1))
        $("")
    }

    if ($mboxes.HasFlag($i,"\Junk") -eq $true) {
        $("Junk mailbox: " + $mboxes.GetName($i))
        $(" >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,0)=" + $mboxes.GetNthFlag($i, 0))
        $(" >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,1)=" + $mboxes.GetNthFlag($i, 1))
        $("")
    }

    if ($mboxes.HasFlag($i,"\Trash") -eq $true) {
        $("Trash mailbox: " + $mboxes.GetName($i))
        $(" >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,0)=" + $mboxes.GetNthFlag($i, 0))
        $(" >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,1)=" + $mboxes.GetNthFlag($i, 1))
        $("")
    }

    $i = $i + 1
}

# Disconnect from the IMAP server.
$success = $imap.Disconnect()
```

And my results are:

```
Junk mailbox: Junk
 >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,1)=\HasNoChildren
 >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,2)=\Junk

Sent mailbox (1): Sent
 >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,1)=\HasChildren
 >> mboxes.GetNthFlag(i,2)=
```

**Conclusion:** This mean that sometimes Sent should be recognized by a Name not by Flag.

btw.
In Polish version of ThunderBird this Mailbox have different name "Wysłane" but location is: similar to "imap://user@domain.com/**Sent**"

Comment: As I'm AutoIt scripter/developer I'm glad to add new link to Chilkat official AutoIt example: https://www.example-code.com/autoit/imap_listMailboxes.asp

Answer (score 1):

Mailboxes contain flags such as "\Sent", "\Trash", "\Junk", etc to indicate the special use mailboxes.

See this example:  https://www.example-code.com/csharp/imap_find_sent_mailbox.asp

Comment: I try to find all type of flags
I read this documentation 
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501

And I'm not able to find list of all possible flags
Could you point me to such list ?

Comment: The main IMAP protocol document is RFC3501. Section 2.3.2 describes the standard flags every IMAP implementation must work with.   Of course, the use of non-standard flags is open-ended...